# Install a particular Ruby version using chef-run

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-workstation

I have been trying to install a particular (latest) version of Ruby using [Chef Workstation](https://www.chef.sh/about/chef-workstation/) and its included `chef-run` CLI.

This is the recipe I'm using for Ruby:

```
package 'ruby' do
  version '2.5.3'
  action :install
end
```

Which, running with the command line

```
chef-run -i /path-to/private_key user@host ruby.rb
```

Produces the not very helpful message:

```
[✔] Packaging cookbook... done!
[✔] Generating local policyfile... exporting... done!
[✖] Applying ruby from ruby.rb to target.
└── [✖] [127.0.0.1] Failed to converge ruby.

The converge of the remote host failed for the
following reason:

  Expected process to exit with [0], but received '100'
```

I have tried to run it with the `-V` flag, or look for a log file, but I can't seem to find it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

raise the `log_level` by setting it to `debug` in the [chef-workstation configuration](https://www.chef.sh/docs/reference/config/#log)

```
$ cat ~/.chef-workstation/config.toml

[log]
level="debug"
```